# Is there a way in JSF to replicate only modified session beans?

Tags: jsf, session, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, managed-bean

If I understand correctly the config parameter below enables session replication across clusters.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableAgressiveSessionDirtying</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

It probably causes all of the `@SessionScoped` managed beans to be replicated. Is there a way to cause JSF to replicate only those that have been modified? I have a JSF application with many `@SessionScoped` managed beans and replicating all of them on each request would be undesirable from performance perspective.

Comment: The problem may be why you have/need so many `@SessionScoped` managed beans...

Comment: Sure, this is a problem. However, how do I avoid it? '@ViewScoped' seems to not replicate across a cluster leaving me with the only option to put all view-specific data that I want to replicate (because I need seemless failover) in '@SessionScoped' beans.